# Fourier transform of the magnitude of the fourier transformed signal

Tags: fourier-transform

I've come to realize that the Fourier transform of an already Fourier transformed signal gives the time-reversal signal.

$$\mathcal F(\mathcal F(x(t)))=x(−t)$$

[ref 1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60258/is-there-any-practical-application-for-performing-a-double-fourier-transform),[ref 2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60258/is-there-any-practical-application-for-performing-a-double-fourier-transform)

However, my question is, if Fourier transformation is applied to the magnitude of the Fourier transformed signal (excluding phase information), is there a way to interpret the returned signal?

$$\mathcal F\{|\mathcal F\{x\}|\}=?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it were the *squared* magnitude, the result would be the auto-correlation function, apart from a time inversion and possibly a scaling factor. If it's just the magnitude, then the result can be characterized as the only even function that has the same Fourier transform magnitude as the original function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the last sentence, or provide some related references?